# What is the use of target attribute in HTML form tag?

Tags: html, forms, target

While I was implementing a file upload progress bar in PHP, I saw this target attribute in `form` tag. The code was like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" 
      method="POST" id="myForm" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      target="hidden_iframe">
```

What is the use of this `target attribute` here?

Actually, after submitting this form data (file) we track the upload progress from another page say `upload.php`. Could we implement this without the target attribute?

Answer (score 23):

That is used to specify in which window you would like to show the response from the remote server upon submitting your form.

Possible values are :

- _blank   - new page
- frame    - show in the iframe with the given name
- _self    - show in the same iframe where the form locates
- _parent  - show in the parent page/iframe of the form's iframe
- _top     - the top most window

Comment: How to add custom title to the new window/tab?

Answer (score 9):

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get" target="_blank">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The target attribute specifies a name or a keyword that indicates where to display the response that is received after submitting the form.

The target attribute defines a name of, or keyword for, a browsing context (e.g. tab, window, or inline frame).

Target Attribute Values:

_blank    :      The response is displayed in a new window or tab

_self      :     The response is displayed in the same frame (this is default)

_parent     :    The response is displayed in the parent frame

_top       :     The response is displayed in the full body of the window

framename : The response is displayed in a named iframe

Now come to your code.

```
method="POST" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="hidden_iframe"
```

indicates after posting the myForm the response (resultant page) will be occupied by 'hidden_iframe'.

Answer (score 7):

Works exactly the same way as anchor target. In your case, it looks like there is an iframe somewhere with `name="hidden_iframe"` - that's where the response from the form will be displayed.

Here is the description of form targets

> A name or keyword indicating where to display the response that is received after submitting the form. In HTML 4, this is the name of, or a keyword for, a frame. In HTML5, it is a name of, or keyword for, a browsing context (for example, tab, window, or inline frame).

Source: [<form> - HTML | MDN #target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target)